# How do I let a function in Haskell depend on the type of its argument?

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, pattern-guards

I tried to write a variation on `show` that treats strings differently from other instances of `Show`, by not including the " and returning the string directly. But I don't know how to do it. Pattern matching? Guards? I couldn't find anything about that in any documentation.

Here is what I tried, which doesn't compile:

```
show_ :: Show a => a -> String
show_ (x :: String) = x
show_ x             = show x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible, you should wrap your values of type `String` up in a `newtype` as @wowofbob suggests.

However, sometimes this isn't feasible, in which case there are two general approaches to making something recognise `String` specifically.

The first way, which is the natural Haskell approach, is to use a type class just like `Show` to get different behaviour for different types. So you might write

```
class Show_ a where
    show_ :: a -> String
```

and then

```
instance Show_ String where
    show_ x = x

instance Show_ Int where
    show_ x = show x
```

and so on for any other type you want to use. This has the disadvantage that you need to explicitly write out `Show_` instances for all the types you want.

@AndrewC shows how you can cut each instance down to a single line, but you'll still have to list them all explicitly. You can in theory work around this, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25954934/96982), but it's not pleasant.

The second option is to get true runtime type information with the `Typeable` class, which is quite short and simple in this particular situation:

```
import Data.Typeable

[...]

show_ :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> String
show_ x =
    case cast x :: Maybe String of
        Just s -> s
        Nothing -> show x
```

This is not a natural Haskell-ish approach because it means callers can't tell much about what the function will do from the type.

Type classes in general give *constrained* polymorphism in the sense that the only variations in behaviour of a particular function must come from the variations in the relevant type class instances. The `Show_` class gives some indication what it's about from its name, and it might be documented.

However `Typeable` is a very general class. You are delegating everything to the specific function you are calling; a function with a `Typeable` constraint might have completely different implementations for lots of different concrete types.

Finally, a further elaboration on the `Typeable` solution which gets closer to your original code is to use a couple of extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Typeable

[...]

show_ :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> String
show_ (cast -> Just (s :: String)) = s
show_ x = show x
```

The use of [`ViewPatterns`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) allows us to write the `cast` inside a pattern, which may fit in more nicely with more complicated examples. In fact we can omit the `:: String` type constraint because the body of this cases forces `s` to be the result type of `show_`, i.e. `String`, anyway. But that's a little obscure so I think it's better to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it into `newtype` and make custom `Show` instance for it:

```
newtype PrettyString = PrettyString { toString :: String }

instance Show PrettyString where
  show (PrettyString s) = "$$" ++ s ++ "$$" -- for example
```

And then use it like below:

```
main = getLine >>= print . PrettyString
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

Copy the prelude's way and use `showList_` as a class function to generate instances for lists so you can override the definition for String.

**Caveat**
For the record, [wowofbob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328267/1598537) using a newtype wrapper is the simple, clean solution I would use in real life, but I felt it was instructive to also look at some of how the Prelude does this.

**intercalate commas by default**

The way this is done in the prelude is to make the `Show` class have a function for showing lists, with a default definition that you can override.

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
```

I'll use `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` to put commas in between stuff:

```
ghci> intercalate "_._" ["intercalate","works","like","this"]
"intercalate_._works_._like_._this"
```

### Make a showList_ class function, and default to show and comma-separated lists.

So now the class with the default implementation of the `showList` function and, importantly, a default `show_` implementation that just uses the ordinary `show` function. To be able to use that, we have to insist that the type is already in the `Show` typeclass, but that's OK as far as I understand you.

```
class Show a => Show_ a where
  show_ :: a -> String
  showList_ :: [a] -> String

  show_ = show
  showList_ xs = '[' : intercalate ", " (map show_ xs) ++ "]"
```

The real Show class uses functions of type `String -> String` instead of `String` directly for efficiency reasons, and a precedence argument to control the use of brackets, but I'll skip all that for simplicity.

### Automatically make instances for lists

Now we can use the `showList` function to provide an instance for lists:

```
instance Show_ a => Show_ [a] where
   show_ xs = showList_ xs
```

### The `Show a =>` superclass makes instances super-easy

Now we come to some instances. Because of our default `show_` implementation, we don't need to do any actual programming unless we want to override the default, which we'll do for Char, because `String ~ [Char]`.

```
instance Show_ Int
instance Show_ Integer
instance Show_ Double

instance Show_ Char where
   show_ c = [c] -- so show_ 'd' = "d". You can put show_ = show if you want "'d'"
   showList_ = id -- just return the string
```

### In practice:

Now that's not much use to hide `"` from your output in ghci, because the default `show` function is used for that, but if we use `putStrLn`, the quotes disappear:

```
put :: Show_ a => a -> IO ()
put = putStrLn . show_
```

```
ghci> show "hello"
"\"hello\""
ghci> show_ "hello"
"hello"
ghci> put "hello"
hello
ghci> put [2,3,4]
[2, 3, 4]
ghci>
```